# Perl: how do I return undef into a list?

Tags: perl

I have a little problem in Perl. Basically, i do something like this:

```
sub myFunction
{
    return (&myOtherFnA(),&myOtherFnB(),&myOtherFnC());
}
sub myOtherFnA() {return 'A';}
sub myOtherFnB() {return undef;}
sub myOtherFnC() {return 'C';}
```

my Problem is: when myOtherFnB() is returning *undef*, i want a list that has *undef* as 2nd element. But when myOtherFnB() does so, i just get a list with 2 elements, that of myOtherFnA() and that of myOtherFnC(). I get:

('A','C')

but i want to get:

('A', undef, 'C')

What syntax do I need to use to stop Perl from removing the return of myOtherFnB() from the list if it is *undef* and actually just put an element of undef into the list?

Comment: If I remove the ampersands in your sub definitions (so it compiles), it works as you say you want it to.  Can you post some working code that exhibits this problem?

Comment: yes, show how you are actually constructing the list in myFunction.  what you show works the way you want.

Comment: Please don't fix the problems in your original post:: it makes nonsense of the solutions that were written to help you

Comment: I just fixed syntax errors not present in my own code but in the short example i gave outlining the problem

Answer (score 7):

I don't know what makes you think you're not getting `undef` in the list. However, there are a number of problems with your code

- Don't use an ampersand `&` when defining subroutines — it is a syntax error
- Don't use an ampersand when calling subroutines. That hasn't been necessary since Perl 4 over twenty years ago
- Don't use prototypes (the parentheses after the subroutine name in the definition) as they don't do what you think, and they're meant for something quite specialised
- Don't use upper case letters in local identifiers: they are reserved for global identifiers like package names

This rewrite of your code fixes the syntax errors and corrects the above problems. As you see, the second element of the returned list is `undef`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub my_function {
  return (
    my_other_function_a(),
    my_other_function_b(),
    my_other_function_c()
  );
}

sub my_other_function_a {
  return 'A';
}

sub my_other_function_b {
  return undef;
}

sub my_other_function_c {
  return 'C';
}


use Data::Dump;
dd [ my_function ];
```

**output**

```
["A", undef, "C"]
```

Comment: Your last bullet point ("Don't use upper case letters in local identifiers") is not nearly as widely accepted as your other points.  That's a local coding style issue; lots of people use camelCase function names.  I've done it myself.

Comment: @cjm: Maybe so, but that doesn't make camel case a good idea. It is mainly used by programmers coming from a Java or Visual Basic background, and very rarely by those whose primary language is Perl. There is no Perl style guide that I know of that recommends camel case, and [`perlstyle`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html) points out that *“It is generally easier to read `$var_names_like_this` than `$VarNamesLikeThis`, especially for non-native speakers of English”*. [This blog post](http://bit.ly/1LnqXUQ) is a useful discussion of Perl naming conventions from a learning programmer.